# Implicit conversion of date literals (not datetime literals)

Tags: mysql, date

When will this query

```
select *
from payments
where payment_date between '2013-06-01' and '2013-09-01';
```

produce different results from

```
select *
from payments
where payment_date between DATE('2013-06-01') and DATE('2013-09-01');
```

where payment_date is a date (not datetime)?

**Update**
I should mention that this is not a hypothetical question but one from my current work project.  There are several places in the code that will need to be reworked, but I'd like to avoid making changes if it's not necessary.

**Also** It is easy to show with particular sets of data that they are the same, but I haven't been able to find a difference if one exists.  If they are the same, I'd like a reference to the manual.  When I searched the relevant part of manual, I found it ambiguous.  If they are different, then an example will suffice.  Thank you for the help.

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) states:

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type
>   conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions
>   occur implicitly.

and specifically comments on DATETIME fields:

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the
>   other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more ODBC-friendly. Note that this is not done for the arguments to IN()! To be safe, always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when doing comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.

Does implicit conversion also hold for DATE strings? The advice is to cast, but I'd like to know in my queries above when can I expect different results.

Comment: The two query should always returns same results. Do you got different results?

Comment: *"When will this query"* ... the answer should be "never."

Comment: @Michael Do you have any references?

Comment: @Dylan That is what I suspected and what I'm seeing but don't feel confident that I haven't missed something.  I'm further confused why the manual would say to cast constants when querying data ranges.  I've updated my question to give some more context.

Comment: No references, just experience.  I've been a MySQL DBA for years and if you're comparing a literal string to a column of type `DATE`, and the string is a valid literal date expression `'YYYY-MM-DD'` there's no situation that I can think of where MySQL wouldn't implicitly cast the string as a date and do the right thing, including using indexes.

Comment: On a related note, using `BETWEEN` for dates is something of an antipattern, as it leads to off-by-one(day)  errors. In reality, most clock and calendar math is actually a closed/open (left-closed, right-open) [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals). `WHERE payment_date >= '2015-01-01' AND payment_date < '2015-02-01'` is more expressive and intuitive than `WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'` and the latter form, while seemingly equivalent, will simply be **wrong** if payment_date ever becomes a `DATETIME`.

Comment: @Michael Thanks.  While I was hoping for a manual reference,  I can certainly appreciate you speaking from experience and upvoted your comments.